# What other graphical methods can be used to represent weathering?

Tags: geology, geochemistry

**Context:**

For one of my reports I have taken samples of a rock from an adjacent creek. I have done XRD analysis to get compositions of calcium, potassium and aluminium.

**My question:**

I know about ternary diagrams, this is the base graphical method I will be using. However, what other *basic* methods could I employ to emphasize the effects of weathering in this experiment? The following data is what I plan on using.

[image: Data]

Comment: What data are you trying to display? Without this we can't really tell you how to display it.

Comment: @bon Apologies. Added.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you probably used XRF, and not XRD. XRF is a method used to obtain chemical compositions. XRD is used to obtain crystal structures.

A ternary diagram would be indeed very useful in this case. Another thing you might want to try is ratios: a plot of Al vs. K/Ca or something similar. Potassium and calcium likely behave differently in different weathering regimes, so it could be useful to show it.

Comment: I will try this! Yeah it was XRF not XRD, I always mix the two. I will definitely try plotting Al against K/Ca thanks!